# How to change language of website on click of button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the localization but I can't figure out how to change language on button click by users choice.

I have the script with localization in another file I didn't think it's important so I didn't include it..

```js
/*here I only tried something but I don't know how to continue*/
document.getElementsById("eng").onclick = function() {

}


let langdata = {
  "languages": {
    "en": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "hi"
      }
    },
    "es": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "hola"
      }
    },
    "fr": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "salut"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="eng">english</button>
<button id="es">spanish</button>
<button id="fr">french</button>
<div lang="en">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
<div lang="es">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
<div lang="fr">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```js
document.getElementById("intButs").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.className === "int") {
    const lang = langdata.languages[tgt.id];
    [...document.querySelectorAll("[lang]")].forEach(ele => {
      if (ele.getAttribute("lang") === tgt.id) {
        const strings = lang.strings;
        Object.keys(strings).forEach(string => {
          const val = strings[string];
          [...ele.querySelectorAll("[data-key=" + string + "]")].forEach(ele => ele.textContent = val);
        })
      }
    })
  }
})


let langdata = {
  "languages": {
    "en": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "hi"
      }
    },
    "es": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "hola"
      }
    },
    "fr": {
      "strings": {
        "hi-txt": "salut"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="intButs">
  <button type="button" class="int" id="en">English</button>
  <button type="button" class="int" id="es">Espagñol</button>
  <button type="button" class="int" id="fr">Français</button>
</div>
<div lang="en">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
<div lang="es">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
<div lang="fr">
  <span data-key="hi-txt" class="text">error</span>
</div>
```